fsnotify watcher uses too much memory
(sorry for bad english)
i am working on a file watcher that will monitor the entire C:\Users tree. but its using too much RAM(around 10 GB). i think there is a memory leak.
i am using "github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify" and path/filepath libraries.
the watcher only watches create and remove events, i ran filepath.WalkDir() without watcher adding the directories and its not the problem.
go func() {//handling events
    for {
        select {
        case event, ok := <-watcher.Events:
            if !ok {
                return
            }
            if event.Has(fsnotify.Create) {
                log.Println("file created: ", event.Name)
            } else if event.Has(fsnotify.Remove) {
                log.Println("file removed: ", event.Name)
            }
        case err, ok := <-watcher.Errors:
            if !ok {
                return
            }
            log.Println("error:", err)
        }
    }
}()

var info fs.FileInfo 
var err1 error 
err = filepath.WalkDir("C:\\Users", func(path string, di fs.DirEntry, err error) error {    
    info, err1 = os.Stat(path)  
    if err1 != nil {        
        log.Print("os.Stat error:")         
        log.Println(err)    
    }   
    if info.IsDir() {       
        err1 = watcher.Add(path)        
        if err1 != nil {            
            log.Println("watcher.add error: ", path)            
            log.Println(err1)       
        }   
    }   
    return nil 
}) 
if err != nil {     
    log.Fatalf("error with walkdir: %v", err) 
} 
log.Println("DONE") 
<-make(chan struct{})


How many directories are under c:\Users? (ie: how many calls to watcher.Add(path) are there?) What is the implementation of watcher?

declared an int and made it go up by 1 each time there isnt an error in watcher.Add(path).  it says 163902

So if the total RAM used is 10GB it uses 64Kb per watched file? And what is the implementation of watcher?

because of my poor english i didnt exactly understand what you meant. but i updated my question and put the watchers event handling.

The windows backend of fsnotify looks like it uses (by default) a 64KB buffer per path added. https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify/blob/v1.7.0/backend_windows.go#L274

There's no memory leak, it's just that you're using fsnotify, which on Windows allocates a 64KB buffer per watched path. See: https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify/blob/v1.7.0/backend_windows.go#L274
You're watching 163902 paths (according to your comments), and 163902 * 64KB is very close to 10GB.
You can configure a smaller buffer size (the minimum is 4KB) using watcher.AddWith(path, fsnotify.WithBufferSize(4096)) instead of watcher.Add(path). The documentation suggests that this will increase the chance of an event overflow (fsnotify.ErrEventOverflow) if there's a "large burst of events", which may or may not be a problem for your use-case.
